# Getting bounds in result with width_bucket

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a query using `width_bucket` and having a column in the results with the bounds of my buckets. Is there a simple way to do this?

My query:

```
SELECT width_bucket(
            (EXTRACT(epoch FROM S.end - S.start) / 60)::integer, 
            array[0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 1000]
       ) AS buckets,
       count(*)
FROM shipments_site S
WHERE S.deleted IS NULL
GROUP BY buckets
ORDER BY buckets
```

Result:

```
buckets | count
1       | 20
2       | 6
3       | 22
4       | 25
5       | 10
6       | 11
7       | 6
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
buckets | count    | interval
1       | 20       | [0, 15]
2       | 6        | [15, 30]
3       | 22       | [30, 45]
4       | 25       | [45, 60]
5       | 10       | [60, 75]
6       | 11       | [75, 90]
7       | 6        | [90, 1000]
```